# Simple Google Spreadsheet For Each Loop?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

It's been a long time since I've coded. I've never looked into scripts for google spreadsheets before. I just want to make a simple effect to edit the spreadsheet. If I understand correctly, this is doable so long as you run it manually?

The syntax is throwing me off too much. My basic goal is to set each cell in a fixed column range to equal itself plus the value in the adjacent column, and then set that second value to 0.

My instinct would be to do something such as

```
CellRange[i][j] selected = C9:D13;
for(i=0,i<selectedrange.length,i++){
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().setValue(selected[i][j]+selected[i][j+1];
SpreadsheetApp.getRange(selected[i][j+1]).setValue(0);
}
```

That's probably terribly wrong but I feel I ought to at least throw my best guess out before asking for help.

Comment: Google-apps-script is java script. There are examples on the web. Good luck.

Comment: This other question sounds quite similar, and the answer may be close to what you're looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616530/google-spreadsheet-script-how-to-loop-range-of-cells-and-set-value-in-adjacent

Answer (score 3):

Say, the goal is to process the range C9:D13 by adding the value in D to the value in C, and then setting D to zero. The code would look like this:

```
function addColumns() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // or getSheetByName
  var range = sheet.getRange("C9:D13");
  var values = range.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    values[i][0] = values[i][0] + values[i][1];
    values[i][1] = 0;
  }
  range.setValues(values);
}
```

Here, `values[i][0]` means values the first column in the range we're working on (namely C) and `values[i][1]` refers to the second. The indexing of JavaScript arrays begins with 0, unlike the numbering of rows in spreadsheets.