# Iterate over an object in Google Apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I thought my question would be answered with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18347921/simple-google-spreadsheet-for-each-loop) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616530/google-spreadsheet-script-how-to-loop-range-of-cells-and-set-value-in-adjacent) but neither is what I'm looking for.

I have an object in Google Script, and want to iterate over each element:

```
var dict = {
    "foo": "a",
    "bar": "b"
};

for each key, element in dict{
    print the key and the element
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I usually do something like that :

```
var dict = {
    "foo": "a",
    "bar": "b"
};

function showProperties(){
  var keys = [];
  for(var k in dict) keys.push(k+':'+dict[k]);
  Logger.log("total " + keys.length + "\n" + keys.join('\n'));
}
```

result in Logger :

[image]

You get the logger in the **script editor/view/Logs**

Comment: you can also use  

"var keys = Object.keys(dict);"

to get your keys.

Answer (score 6):

With [V8 runtime](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime):

```js
var dict = {
  "foo": "a",
  "bar": "b"
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(dict)) {
  Logger.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```