# Google Apps Script for each causes error, but for does not

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, foreach

I've got a simple Google Apps Script code like this:

```
function throwsError(){
  var inboxThreads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  var sliceArr = inboxThreads.slice(0, 3);
  Logger.log(sliceArr.length);

  for each (var thread in sliceArr){
    Logger.log(inboxThreads.containsThread(thread));
  }
}

function doesNotThrowError(){
  var inboxThreads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  var sliceArr = inboxThreads.slice(0, 3);
  Logger.log(sliceArr.length);

  for (var i = 0; i < sliceArr.length; i++){
    Logger.log(inboxThreads.containsThread(sliceArr[i]));
  }
}

Array.prototype.containsThread = function(thread){
  Logger.log("Here");
  Logger.log(thread);
  return this.filter(function(t){ return t.getId() == thread.getId(); }).length > 0;
}
```

As the function names indicate, `throwsError()` throws an error of `TypeError: Cannot find function getId in object function (thread) {...}.`. `doesNotThrowError()` runs perfectly without issue. The only difference between them is that one uses a `for` loop and the other uses a `for each` loop.

The log output of `throwsError()` is as follows:

[image]

It seems that there are only 3 items in my `sliceArr` array, but the `containsThread` is being called 4 times. (Additionally, the 4th time it seems that it is passing in the `containsThread` function into itself as the parameter). Any ideas what could be causing this?

My inclination is that this is a bug with Google Apps Script, but I wanted to check here in case anyone else had some insight. Note that Google Apps Script [works on JS 1.6 with some portions of 1.7 and 1.8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Apps_Script)

Comment: `for each (var thread in easyThreads)` doesn't compile for me. Shouldn't it be `for (var thread in easyThreads)`? Or maybe this is peculiar to Google Apps Script...

Comment: @SteveO'Connor I think it's particular to Google Apps Script

Comment: @SteveO'Connor I just changed my question to have the minimum reproducible steps (basically, without the "easyLabel" requirement)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For-each over an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: @TheMaster Note that in some cases, Google Apps Script does not work the same as typical JavaScript. This is one of those cases. [Here is an example of GAS for each](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46782189/2246411)

Comment: This isn't one of those cases. You should read the references in the second answer of your linked question(especially the MDN one) and the linked  duplicate question regarding how `for-in` works and why it shouldn't be used in arrays or if used, how it should be used.

Comment: Don't use `for each in`, period.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use for each

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in

> The for each...in statement is deprecated as the part of ECMA-357 (E4X) standard. E4X support has been removed. Consider using for...of instead.
>
> Firefox now warns about the usage of for each...in and it no longer works starting with Firefox 57.
>
> Please see [Warning: JavaScript 1.6's for-each-in loops are deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/For-each-in_loops_are_deprecated) for migration help.