# Script for cleaning up text in a google sheet (for non-engineers...)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm sure this question has been asked a million times, my apologies. I've been reading around for a few hours and still haven't found a simple solution for non-engineers.

I'm literally just trying to find and replace multiple strings of text from a google sheet - normally for something like this I would make a macro, but google sheet's macro utility doesn't support their find and replace operation.

The script I've haphazardly thrown together from other stackoverflow answers is:

```html
function runcleanup(){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  //  get the current data range values as an array
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();  

  // Replace Subject Names
  cleanup(values, "messy text 1", "");
  cleanup(values, "messy text 2", "");
  cleanup(values, "messy text 3", "");
  cleanup(values, "messy text 4", "");

  // Write all updated values to the sheet, at once
  sheet.getDataRange().setValues(values);
}

function cleanup(values, to_replace, replace_with) {
  //loop over the rows in the array
  for(var row in values){
    //use Array.map to execute a replace call on each of the cells in the row.
    var replaced_values = values[row].map(function(original_value) {
      return original_value.toString().replace(to_replace,replace_with);
    });

    //replace the original row values with the replaced values
    values[row] = replaced_values;
  }
}
```

And naturally it doesn't work - I'm sure there's a simple fix to this that I'm just glossing over due to unfamiliarity with javascript - the script runs, it just doesn't replace any text. If anyone sees a fix, you'd be pulling at least one forsaken soul out of the abyss!

Cheers

Comment: I think that your script works when the values can be used for replacing. So in order to correctly understand about your issue, can you provide the sample values of `values` in your question? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: You mean the data range in the spreadsheet? An example of column A would be `_engraving_id: 28555767906379, _engraving_price: 599, One_Line_Engraving: BTL` where in this case the text meant to remain would be "BTL." Additionally there are some empty fields interspersed.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About `You mean the data range in the spreadsheet?`, it's No. That is `values` of `var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();`. Because for example, in your updated script, when `values` is `var values = [["messy text 1a", "messy text 2b", "messy text 3c", "messy text 4d"]];`, `[["a","b","c","d"]]` is retrieved by 4 times of `cleanup()`. In this case, the script works. So in order to correctly understand about your situation, I thought that it is required to know the values of `values`.

Comment: I may be missing that block, how would you write those values? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Blake, we need a sample sheet link with sample input data, and a second sheet with how you want the output to look, you probably can just solve this issue with regular formulas, why use Google App Script when you are unfamiliar with it without first exhausting all formula options?

Comment: I will look into formulas. This has been a rabbit hole where you anticipate spending ten minutes copying and pasting an existing script into a google sheet and instead end up trying to learn an unfamiliar coding language. When you google search "Find and replace automate google sheet" it's nothing but javascript - oftentimes for things this mainstream there is a simple and configurable method. Let me make a quick sample sheet, I'm pretty invested at this point and I'd definitely use the technique in the future. Thanks for chiming in by the way.

Comment: Here is an example google sheet, where the first sheet is the imported data and the second sheet is the cleaned version after some find/replace.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iPNpQ4n_UmJztRtFJ0vFbBrtzoh4h2hb_WWfaQmRbwg/edit?usp=sharing

Cheers

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46693496/for-each-loop-in-google-apps-script

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you may want to use the [Text Finder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder) class in order to find and replace text of all of your sheet.

You can use the code below to accomplish your goals. The idea is that for each element in the `stringsToRemove` variable, a find-and-replace operation will be issued substituting every occurrence for an empty string.

```js
function runCleanup() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var stringsToRemove = ['messy text 1', 'messy text 2', 'messy text 3', 'messy text 4'];

  stringsToRemove.forEach(function (s) {
    sheet.createTextFinder(s).replaceAllWith("");
  });
}
```